# Function to Return Datatypes in SML

Tags: sml

For homework, I need to design an SML function that returns the type of a custom datatype which matches some input data.

Here's the general idea:  we are given a custom datatype **typ**--

```
datatype typ = typ1 
              |typ2
              |typ3
              .
              .
              .
              |typn
```

The function we're supposed to write has this type:

```
(foo -> typ option)
```

Since the function isn't returning a string but instead **typ option**, I understand the function, on the most basic level, as needing to look something like this --

```
hw_fun x =
  case x of 
    p1 => SOME typ1
   |p2 => SOME typ2
   .
   .
   .
   |pn => SOME typn
   |_  => NONE
```

--assuming p1 matches typ1, etc.  My question is, how do I make a datatype the return value of a matching case?

Hope that makes sense, thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I sense some conceptual confusion – `typ1`, `typ2`, etc are not *types* but *values*. They work exactly like, for instance, `true` and `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type inferencing will take care of you. Consider the following.

```
datatype foo = Bar | Baz;

fun wooble n =
  case n of
    1 => SOME Bar
  | 2 => SOME Baz
  | _ => NONE;
```

The `wooble` function is inferred to have type `int → foo option`.  If I wished to use explicit type nnotations, I might write:

```
fun wooble (n : int) : foo option =
  case n of
    1 => SOME Bar
  | 2 => SOME Baz
  | _ => NONE;
```

Of course, in this case the `case` expression is extraneous.

```
fun wooble 1 = SOME Bar
  | wooble 2 = SOME Baz
  | wooble _ = NONE
```

You only get in trouble with type inferencing if you try to return something of a different type from your function. E.g.

```
fun wooble 1 = SOME Bar
  | wooble 2 = SOME Baz
  | wooble _ = "NONE"
```

Comment: One last question: one of the constructors for typ is Datatype of string.  Suppose pn matched the Datatype constructor, and carried with it a specific string value.  How could I return SOME Datatype "specific_string"?  Thanks!

Comment: `SOME (Constructor "String")`

Comment: Thanks Chris!  I appreciate it.  The parenthesis mucked me up.  Makes total sense though.

Comment: I mean, you could also do something like `let val v = Constructor "String" in SOME v end` to avoid parentheses, but that seems silly.